# Bootstrap 4 jquery not working rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I downloaded the bootstrap 4 theme from this website: https://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4-theme

and copied the html and css files into the appropriate places in my rails application, which worked perfectly.  However, when incorporating the javascript code, which contains jquery, it does not work.

I tested it out with javascript only and that worked - but it seems that there is an issue with the jquery part.  This is what the jquery looks like:

```
(function($) {
"use strict";

$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 60
});    

$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($ele.attr('href')).offset().top - 60)
    }, 1450, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#collapsingNavbar li a').click(function() {
    /* always close responsive nav after click */
    $('.navbar-toggler:visible').click();
});

$('#galleryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('#galleryImage').attr("src",$(e.relatedTarget).data("src"));
});

})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas as to why it might not be working and how I can fix it?

EDIT: I changed the file to look like the following:

```
$( document ).on('page:change', function() {
"use strict";

$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 60
});    

$('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
    var $ele = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: ($($ele.attr('href')).offset().top - 60)
    }, 1450, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#collapsingNavbar li a').click(function() {
    /* always close responsive nav after click */
    $('.navbar-toggler:visible').click();
});

$('#galleryModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('#galleryImage').attr("src",$(e.relatedTarget).data("src"));
});

})
```

None of the JQuery is working.  I also tried using an example from a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-sns5tNdTY) and it also didn't work.

Comment: why do you use bind? please explain what is not working we don't read minds

Comment: Without any additional specific information, the only things that stand out are: 1. don't use `bind`, use `on`. 2. wrap everything inside the IIFE in a `$(function() { ... });` block (document ready event)

Comment: Anything in the JavaScript error console?

Comment: None of the JQuery is working.  @Derek, I did what you suggested and it still doesn' work. I also tried wrapping it in $(document).ready(function()...)
(and now when I click on the jquery functionality in the code, I do get console errors)

Comment: Have you used jQuery min file? If yes then please recheck path.